# Return boolean using IHTTPActionResult and reading the result

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API endpoint that checks to see if a user exists in a table within the database. I would like the API to be consistent and return an `IHTTPActionResult` just like all the other endpoints. I am having trouble figuring out how to pass back a boolean and then read the result as a strongly typed result.

```
[Route("DoesUserExist/{userId:int}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoesUserExist(int userId)
{
    bool result;
    result = myServiceLayer.DoesUserIdExist(userId); // Code that checks the table
    return Ok(result);
}
```

This code returns an HTTP 200 and the text `true` or `false`. Is this the best way to return a boolean value? Do I need to read the result as just text? Is there a way to read the result as a boolean?

Comment: If you want to use HTTP codes, you could return a 404 not found code if the user does not exist. Otherwise I would suggest that you return JSON and parse the result on the client side.

Comment: I was wondering if the use of HTTP Codes might be the answer. However, I usually use HTTP Codes to denote whether that call was successful, no matter what the result is.

Comment: I suggest changing the web method to HEAD and returning 200 OK or 404 NOT FOUND.  Also change the route to the same as the route for getting the user, instead of "DoesUserExist".  Then you just issue a HTTP HEAD request to see if it exists.

Comment: See http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Comment: I think you should use HTTP codes, it is better than returning a json result. you can specify exactly what is going on. e.g not authorized, not found, created, deleted. Here is the list of codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes